# Probability of creating degenerate binary search tree

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm attempting a problem but am not sure if my approach is correct.

If the integers $1$ to $n$ are inserted in arbitrary order into a binary search tree (where each possible order is equally likely), what is the probability that the resulting BST will have a completely degenerate structure (each node in the BST has at most one child)?

My approach: Each ordering of the numbers $1$ to $n$ gives a unique BST, so there are $n!$ possible BSTs. Now suppose we have to form a degenerate BST - if the initial number (root node) that we select is anything between $1$ and $n$ (exclusive), then surely that node will have to have two children.

So we must either start with $1$ or $n$. The rest of the tree can be formed in a similar way - out of the remaining numbers, we have to select either the minimum or maximum as the next node, and so on. Since there are $n-1$ steps of selecting between the max and min (till only the last number - the leaf node remains), there are $2^{n-1}$ ways of doing so.

The probability should then be $2^{n-1}/n!$. I'm not sure if this is correct - have I missed out on anything?

Comment: This looks correct to me.